# Creating an installation bash script with the python csv module

Tags: python, linux, bash, unix

The following code should give me a "working bash script"

```
box_category=GET_COMBOBOX_value(self,self.combobox_category2,False)
list_path=Data_Location+"/program-data/programs_to_install.csv"
list=csv.reader(open(list_path),delimiter='|')

bash_file=path+"/install_programs"
if os.path.exists(bash_file):
    os.remove(bash_file)

with open(bash_file, "ab") as f:
    bash_list=csv.writer(f,delimiter='|')   
    bash_list.writerow(["#!/bin/bash"])
    bash_list.writerow([" "])
    string="if [ \"$(id -u)\" != \"0\" ]; then echo \"You need root permission for installing programs.\" 1>&2; exit 1; fi"
    print string        
    bash_list.writerow([string])

    for row in list :
        bash_list.writerow(["apt-get --yes install "+row[0]])

time.sleep(0.2)
os.system("chmod a+x '"+bash_file+"'")
```

At the first look, it is "almost" correctly, it generates me this bash file:

```
#!/bin/bash

"if [ ""$(id -u)"" != ""0"" ]; then echo ""You need root permission for installing programs."" 1>&2; exit 1; fi"
apt-get --yes install 0ad
apt-get --yes install audacity
apt-get --yes install banshee
apt-get --yes install barrage
..etc..
```

but:

- When i execute the bash file, i get the error  `bash: ./install_programs: /bin/bash^M: bad interpreter: No such file or directory`

If i erase everything until the first `apt-get ..` line, and add the bash extension ".sh"
the interpreter recognize it.

- the csv module is not writing good

`"if [ \"$(id -u)\" != \"0\" ]; then echo \"You need root permission for installing programs.\" 1>&2; exit 1; fi"`

it should write:

`if [ "$(id -u)" != "0" ]; then echo "You need root permission for installing programs." 1>&2; exit 1; fi`

- And my last mystery, is that even if i fix all those things manually, once i execute the script it doesn't installs any program, even if the commands are right, and work if i use them in a termial..

i get an outputs like this:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package 0ad
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package audacity
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
```

Comment: Why are you using the `csv` module when you're just trying to create a single column? Why not just write each line to the file as a line?

Comment: yeah you're right, just I've been using so much the csv module that it was like a reflex to me. I'm gonna check it with out the csv

Comment: By the way, it might be easier to write this using one big template instead of generating line by line. Nothing ever changes except the list of packages to install, right? And `apt-get` can take multiple packages on one line (and is even more efficient that way, because it doesn't have to keep checking deps). So, you can just take an already-built bash script for a single installation, replace the package name with `{}`, and store it as a multi-line string literal named template. then your whole big program becomes `f.write(template.format(' '.join(row[0] for row in rows)`.

Comment: @abarnert great advice. just, since i don't have the permission to edit your post, there are missing some ")",  `f.write(template.format(' '.join(row[0] for row in rows)))`

Comment: Thanks for the catch. For some reason, I make that error all the time when I use `format`; even if I double the paren-match flashing in emacs, I still do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The whole point of CSV is that it's for Comma-Separated Values—that is, multiple columns on each line, separated by commas. Which means that if any of your values happens to have a comma in it, that value has to be quoted (or escaped). And those quoting rules mean that if any of your values happens to have a quote character in it, the value has to be quoted to deal with that. So, instead of this:

```
if [ "$(id -u)" != "0" ]; then echo "You need root permission for installing programs." 1>&2; exit 1; fi
```

… you end up with this:

```
"if [ ""$(id -u)"" != ""0"" ]; then echo ""You need root permission for installing programs."" 1>&2; exit 1; fi"
```

Which is of course not a valid bash command.

The easy solution is to just not use the `csv` module; just write your lines to the file, instead of trying to turn each one into a list of one column for the `csv` module to write in hopes of getting the line you wanted.

```
with open(bash_file, "a") as f:
    f.write("#!/bin/bash\n")
    f.write(" \n")
    string="if [ \"$(id -u)\" != \"0\" ]; then echo \"You need root permission for installing programs.\" 1>&2; exit 1; fi"
    print string        
    f.write(string + "\n")
    for row in list:
        f.write("apt-get --yes install " + row[0] + "\n")
```

---

If you're getting sick of typing all those explicit newlines all over, you can wrap the `write` function up:

```
def writeline(f, line):
    f.write(line + '\n')
```

And then, everywhere you did this:

```
f.write(string + "\n")
```

… you can instead do this:

```
writeline(f, string)
```

This is probably a good idea; otherwise, you're going to forget the "\n" on one line—or, worse, mistype it—and spend an hour debugging your code that's obviously correct no matter how much you stare at it, and yet still doesn't work…

---

This error:

```
bash: ./install_programs: /bin/bash^M: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```

… is *also* caused by using the `csv` module.

The default CSV dialect uses Windows-style newlines—that is, each row ends in `'\r\n'`. (See [`Dialect.lineterminator`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.Dialect.lineterminator) in the documentation.) But `bash` wants Unix-style newlines—that is, each line ends in `'\n'`. So, it treats that extra `'\r'` as if it were part of the actual line. So, on the shebang line, instead of thinking you want `'/bin/bash'` as your interpreter, it thinks you want `'/bin/bash\r'`—which is a perfectly valid filename, but there's no file with that name.

---

And your last problem could very well be exactly the same problem. An extra invisible `'\r'` character may be preventing the `fi\r` from matching the `if`, or causing you to try to install a package named `'0ad\r'` instead of `'0ad'`, etc.

---

A couple of side notes:

- Never call a variable `list`; that hides the built-in type/function of the same name, which you may want to use. Also, although it comes up less often, `string` is the name of a stdlib module, so usually avoid that too.
- If you write your string literal with single quotes instead of double, you don't need to escape every double-quote inside of it. Or you can just use tripled (single or double) quotes, and you don't need to escape either kind of quotes, or even newlines: `"""if [ "$(id -u)" != "0" ]; then echo "You need root permission for installing programs." 1>&2; exit 1; fi"""`

Comment: I realized that i used the csv module because it is reeeally easy to write "in a new line", it took me some time make it work with the \n stuff but now it works. Thanks for your answer i learned a lot of stuff!

Comment: There is one thing that still not understanding. If i was using "|" as separator and escaping the right quotes, why did i got doubles quotes? a simple "print" test shows that i did the escaping right. If you "already answered it" don't bother to answer, I'm gonna give it some more thinking hehe

Comment: @rsm: If you use the default quoting mode, it will quote anything with your separator _or a quote character_. You got the escaping right, but that just means you correctly built a string value with quote characters in it, with the `csv.Dialect` dutifully quoted for you. You can choose other quoting/escaping rules or parameters for them, that's just the default one. Read the docs for all the options, and play with them for a while to get the idea of how they work in different edge cases.

Answer (score 0):

The first clue is probably in the `"^M"`. This is a carriage return, and is regarded by the shebang execution mechanism to be part of the executable path. Don't use text files created in Windows in other environments without appropriate sanitization. You overcame that by using `sh` to run the script anyway. As @abarnert points out in his/her answer, the `csv` module isn't required for output and indeed gets in the way.

Comment: I don't think he's using Windows to create the file—and, even if he were, he's explicitly opening the file in binary mode ("ab"), so it's not going to do newline translation anyway. That's caused by the `csv` module too.